# Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-hooks

Estoy levantando mi primera app en react en asp.net core, y al abrir mi page me devuelve el siguiente mensaje.

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:

Por lo que he leído react maneja una serie de reglas para declarar e invocar funciones, en mi caso tengo este ejemplo que vengo contruyendo.

```
export default function Login() {
        const navigate = useNavigate()
        const [login, setLogin] = useState({
            user: "",
            pswd: "",
        })
        const [messageLogin, setMessageLogin] = useState()
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (localStorage.getItem('checklistPeruBusUser')) {
                var localStorageUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checklistPeruBusUser'))
                axios.post(dRouteLogin, {
                    cO_USUA: localStorageUser.CO_USUA,
                    nO_CLAV: CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(localStorageUser.NO_HPWD, 'secret-key').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
                })
                    .then(res => {
                        if (res.data[0].ID_RESPONSE == 'OK') {
                            navigate('/dashboard')
                        } else {
                            localStorage.removeItem('checklistPeruBusUser')
                            localStorage.removeItem('accessPeruBusUser')
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        localStorage.removeItem('checklistPeruBusUser')
                        localStorage.removeItem('accessPeruBusUser')
                    })
            }
        }, [])
    
        async function handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let USUA = login.user
            let CLAV = login.pswd
    
            
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div className="login-grid">
                    <div className="login-cover">
                        <div className="login-cover-logo">
                            <div className="img">
                                <img src={logowhite} alt="PeruBus" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="login-cover-brand">
                            {/* <span>Checklist e incidencias</span> */}
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div className="login-control">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="img">
                                <img src={logo} alt="PeruBus" />
                            </div>
                            <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
                            <h3>Inicie sesión</h3>
                            <form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>
                                <div className="form-control">
                                    <label>Usuario</label>
                                    <input type="text" required onChange={(e) => setLogin({ ...login, user: e.currentTarget.value })} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-control">
                                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                                    <input type="password" required onChange={(e) => setLogin({ ...login, pswd: e.currentTarget.value })} />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit">Ingresar</button>
                                <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{messageLogin}</span>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <small>v0.01</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <ToastContainer />
            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Puede ser el `onChange` del `input`, crea una función handler en vez de llamar al `setLogin` directamente desde el `onChange`, ademas las declaraciones de aséstate deben estar al inicio del componente, avisanos del resultado

Comment: Lo que he notado es que cuando comento <ToastContainer /> en mi código el error desaparece, será algún conflicto con la librería?